# CSS z-index 999 not working on Google Chrome and Safari browser

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome, z-index, opacity

We need to display white text color on slider text. For this we apply black background color with 0.65 opacity CSS on slider image to display slider white text readable. For opacity we apply following CSS:

**`.zlslides .ms-slide-link {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.65;
}`**

Following is slider text HTML:
`<h2 class="master_event_title">Brasil Loves Baile Funk ft Naldo • Dance Party</h2>`

Following is CSS for text:

**`.master_event_title {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: 41%;
    z-index: 999;
}`**

After applying above CSS with  z-index: 999; slider text display in white color.

**But issue is that slider text color only display white color in Fire Fox browser. In Google Chrome and Safari Browser slider text color not display in white color.** With out z-index: 999; text not display in white color. For Google Chrome and Safari Browser slider text color we apply following CSS:

**`@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
.master_event_title{z-index: 999;}
}`**

But above CSS also not working. If any one know this issues solutions then please replay me. Here i have attached Google chrome browser issues screen shot. So please review that.

[image]

Thanks,
Ketan.

Comment: So basic requirement is you need to show some text on top of image? Or you want to to show different text on different images in a slide?

Comment: Please provide a simplified example of your problem at https://jsfiddle.net/ or other similar websites

Comment: @Veer I think the requirement is showing text on top of image, and to make the text readable, He wants to add dark opacity over image.

Comment: Please add your HTML as well, CSS alone doesn't help us identify the problem.

Comment: Then he can add image in html and to the div he can add background-color: black and then give opacity to div. A fiddle will be great.

Comment: What slider are you using?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the z-index of the background to a lower stack value than the text?

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Answer (score -1):

instead of using separate properties for background-color and opacity, use:

```
.zlslides .ms-slide-link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0 , 0.65);
}
```

Comment: It's not what OP requested, I would put this as comment under the question.

Comment: To be honest, this may actually be a solution to the question. The question itself is unclear and requires a reproducible example.

Comment: @hdev,  I have applied your CSS `.zlslides .ms-slide-link {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0 , 0.65);
}`  but till show my issues in Google chrome browser.